# Working with AOSP SuperUser

Tags: android, android-source, su, superuser, custom-rom

I'm trying to include the SuperUser application and su binary in my ROM (by AOSP method). I'm using `android-6.0.1_r79 (Marshmallow)` as my base AOSP code.

[*[Similar question(s) has been answered earlier, but all previous discussions were prior to Android KitKat and does not solve current AOSP/Superuser issues.]*]

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/codewalkerster/Superuser#building-with-aosp-cyanogenmod-etc) and after a few hiccups and with some help from Google I was able to make a successful build. I'm using the su repositories listed [here](https://github.com/wvengen/Superuser/blob/feature/try-fix-aosp-build/local_manifest.xml).

I was able to verify that su binary present in `/system/xbin` was from [wvengen/su.c](https://github.com/wvengen/Superuser/blob/master/Superuser/jni/su/su.c) by adding some logs. However, there was no Superuser application present in the ROM.

2nd problem I'm facing is that `/system/xbin/su` is accessible only to adb shell and not to other apps. 
By default su binary has the following permissions:

```
root@generic:/system/xbin # ls -l | grep su
-rwsr-x--- root     shell      488692 2017-04-16 16:20 su
```

I changed it to:

```
root@generic:/system/xbin # chmod +rx su
root@generic:/system/xbin # chmod +s su
root@generic:/system/xbin # ls -l | grep su
-rwsr-sr-x root     shell      488692 2017-04-16 16:20 su
```

But still other applications do not get su access

```
root@generic:/system/xbin # run-as com.test
root@generic:/system/xbin $ ls -l | grep su
lstat './su' failed: Permission denied
```

whereas all other binaries are executable (eg. /system/xbin/sqlite3) under com.test.

I also tried to change the su permissions in [fs_config.c](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/system/core/libcutils/fs_config.c#126) but it did not work.

So please provide me some pointers to:

1. Understand why Superuser.apk is absent from my ROM
2. How to make su binary available to other Applications

Comment: If you put SuperSU in priv-app, it can root the device.

Comment: @SamMearns From where will SuperSU.apk get the su binary from?

Comment: I believe it's either embedded in the apk or it downloads it. @PC.

Comment: Thanks @SamMearns. I'll look into this approach. I'd still like to know if my problems can be solved using AOSP approach.

Comment: @SamMearns Adding SuperSU.apk to priv-app did not work. Technically any application cannot remount system partition without proper su binary. remount is required to place su and su is required to remount. So I don't see how this approach can work!

Comment: Okay @PC. I think I got confused by SuperSU's ability to update